# Exclude substring from capture group

Tags: regex, pcre

I am using a system which takes a PCRE compatible regular expression.

The system stores capture group 1 into a database.

I need to capture two halves of a string with a delimiter, excluding the delimiter, as a single capture group.

Given the string: "I want to capture this bit but not this bit and definitely this bit"

I get that I could create a regex like:

```
([A-Za-z\s]*) but not this bit([A-Za-z\s]*)
```

This would give me two capture groups:
Group 1: "I want to capture this bit"
Group 2: " and definitely this bit"

However, I miss out on half my result, as group 1 is all that is stored.

Comment: Why don't you try this http://regex101.com/r/lD8nJ2/2 ?

Comment: you're missing the `g` modifier which tells the regex to continue after 1st match, so usually `/([A-Za-z/s]*) but not this bit([A-Za-z/s]*)/g` , depending on your PCRE system the syntax could be different

Comment: One approach is to first check whether input contains ` but not this bit`. If it does then remove ` but not this bit` from input and capture rest of it captured group #1.

Comment: Did you mean to use `\s` instead of `/s` in the patterns?  It isn't material to the larger problem, but as written, the second part would not match because of the space before `and`.  I rather suspect that within the constraints you appear to be working under, there isn't a way to do what you want in a single operation.

Comment: It isn't possible to concatenate two separated substrings in a single capture group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I had to do this programmatically, rather than relying on a single regex. Turns out Casimir was correct that it wasn't possible to do this with a single capture group, even following hwnd's suggestion, as below:

[branch-reset does not result in a combined capture group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Sin.png)

Also, yes, I had the wrong slash :-P

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking about the branch reset feature. But this is only an assumption.

```
(?|([a-zA-Z\s]+) but not this bit|([a-zA-Z\s]+))
```

As stated in the comments, you can can fix this using the correct syntax.

```
([A-Za-z\s]+) but not this bit([A-Za-z\s]+)
```

Comment: Yeah, the branch-reset group is nice, but it's not the tool for this job.  The problem was that the second group was always capturing an empty string, and you solved that by changing the `/s` to `\s`.  Changing the `*` to `+` was good, too; you should never use `*` if you can use `+` instead.  It just leaves you open to poor performance and silent failures.